# Cycle focus and sort with isotope

Tags: jquery-isotope

I have something like [this](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/sorting.html) example, the sorting works well. As far I can see isotope uses some kind of cache and then using CSS rules, it sorts everything in the final view. But it actually does not sort the DOM thereby the focus cycle does not work as expected. Is there something I can do to fix this behavior besides sorting the DOM by myself?

Comment: are you asking how to re-order the tab index after applying sort/filter etc with isotope?

Comment: This would require you to either extend the isotope plugin, or write your own reorder function, setting the tabindex property of each element, based on the relative position of each of the dom items from top left, setting order of precedence to top, then left (getting the `offset()` prop.  I'll take a crack at a function for you, but I'm just going to sleep, so might not get to it tonight.

Comment: worked on this for over 20 mins, made progress, but realized it def needs to be made into a plugin extension to account for layout options (are all objects same height width? in even rows?), existing tabindex range of matching elements, and a few other small things. Concerned about browser compatibility as well...

Comment: in my case all elements have the same size,i was thinking in use the sortobject that use isotope to perform my sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end, my solution was calculating the tabindex of each element using his absolute position.

```
function sortFocus(sortClass) {
    var button = $('div.isotope-button').first() ;       

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('div.isotope-button.' + sortClass).each(function(index) {
            var pos = $(this).position(), posx = (pos.left) / button.outerWidth(), posy = ((pos.top) / button.outerHeight()) + 1;
            $(this).find('a').attr('tabindex', posy + '' + posx);
        });
    }, 1000);
}
```

some thoughts:

- isotope plugin does not have callback function after the animation.
- the calculation is based in the size of the buttons, assuming all the buttons are of the same size. I don't know  if works with different sizes
- In my case each isotope-button has an inner link.

Comment: This was something I was looking at as well. Thanks for posting your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

This also works, filteredItems is always returned in the correct order.

```
$myIsotope.on('arrangeComplete', function (e, filteredItems) {
  var tabIndex = 1;
  $(filteredItems).each(function (index, item) {
    $(item.element).find('a.title').attr('tabindex', tabIndex);
    tabIndex++;
  });
});
```